Mapping multiple columns value to dictionary entity property
I have an existing on-premises application that works without Entity Framework.
Each customer has its own installation and different SQL Server database instance.
All the databases have the most of the tables and columns in common, but a customer can add columns. These columns exist only in the customer db instance.
Let's make a simple example: the standard database has a table
Employee with columns Id, Number, Name.
Customer 1 decided to add a column Role and customer 2 to add the columns StartDate and EndDate.
Customer 1 - Database 1 - Table Employee:



Id
Number
Name
Role




1
15
John
Office administrator


2
12
Paul
Office manager



Customer 2 - Database 2 - Table Employee:



Id
Number
Name
StartDate
EndDate




1
8
Mark
2024-01-01
2024-12-31


2
17
Jack
2023-07-01
2024-12-31



Now, without EF, my class model has the standard properties and a dictionary with all the custom columns data (key: column name, value: column value) of the record, something like this:
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Number { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, object> CustomFields { get; set; }

Employee reading example by customer 1:
Id: 1
Number: 15
Name: John
CustomFields: [<"Role", "Office administrator">]

Id: 2
Number: 12
Name: Paul
CustomFields: [<"Role", "Office manager">]`

Employee reading example by customer 2:
Id: 1
Number: 8
Name: Mark
CustomFields: [<"StartDate", "2024-01-01">, <"EndDate", "2024-12-31">]

Id: 2
Number: 17
Name: Jack
CustomFields: [<"StartDate", "2023-07-01">, <"EndDate", "2024-12-31">]

How can I implement this with EF Core?
I tried some solutions but they didn't work:

Inheritance Using columns not defined in model
Shadow or indexer properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#configuring-indexer-properties

The expectation is to find a configuration that works automatically (maybe in the OnModelCreating?).
The database has hundred of tables, it's not possible to manage every query.

OnModelCreating is bad idea. You have to use UseModel during context configuring.

Ok and what can I do in the UseModel?

You can provide configured model. Search in internet for UseModel usage.

Hi @fedegiamporcaro, have your tried shadow property? Shadow properties in EF Core can be used to store data without directly being part of the class. Since each customer's database has its own schema, you can map the additional columns dynamically and store them in a dictionary (CustomFields).

Yes, I tried but I don't think it works. Do you have some advices or resources about?

You can use TEXT data type for the CustomFields Column in the database and store all the data in JSON format and then make use of Value Conversion to serialize and deserialize your Dicitonary CustomFields to and from the database.

I can't edit database schema because it's used by an other application.
